# How to configure DropZone to hide file information

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am not creating a Dropzone form, but a div and then i configure it using JavaScript and Jquery.

Anyone can explain me how do i configure my DropZone to hide the files information, name and size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#layout):

The HTML that is generated for each file by dropzone is defined with the option previewTemplate which defaults to this:

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
  <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```

Just set the previewTemplate option to the above HTML but with `.dz-filename` and `.dz-size` elements removed.

The template you want is probably:

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
  <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```